# Eclipse product development - Java runtime differences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing Eclipse product. The JRE of Eclipse and the JRE in product definition are the same (which is jre7 for 32bit). 
I can run this product as Eclipse Application mode of debug (selecting run as application). 
Also, the product itself is opened without problem. 
But when I run the product in Eclipse as Eclipse Application mode (with Run as Product option) I get 
"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap".

What should be the problem here? "Run as Application" works fine but the result differs from real product environment.

Answer (score 0):

Open 'Run > Run Configurations' and find your application in 'Eclipse Application' On the Arguments tab of the configuration in the 'VM arguments' section add a -XmxNNNN argument to increase the help size.

Comment: Thank you. That won't help unfortunately. I changed the configuration's max heap size as you told, and I also changed it from eclipse.ini. Still get same error.